# How to check the value of a variable php

Tags: php

I just started php
I want to check the value of a variable
If it was not a null, it would return the video to me
The part I want to edit
$ response ['type']

```
$post=$posts[$i];
    $response['id']=$post['id'];
    $response['title']=strip_tags($post['title']);
    $response['content']=str_replace("\n","",strip_tags($post['content']));
    $response['date']=explode(" ",$post['date'])[0];
    $response['video']=$post['attachments'][0]['url'];
    $response['pic']=$post['thumbnail_images']['medium']['url'];
```

> > > > > $response['type']=--test-- if $video null! echo viceo;

Comment: So... you're asking how to write an `if` statement in PHP?  Start with any PHP tutorial.

Comment: can you simplified your question that what exactly you want? remove those extra design and fancy text like `--test-- if`.Write appropriate things. It's misleading

Comment: Reading [control-structures.elseif](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) and a lot of other pages on php.net would be a good start to get it to work and it will bring you into the right direction..

Answer (score 0):

Not sue what you are asking :/ If you are asking how to check some variable type u can do it with if statement... [If manual - php](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

So basically if expression evaluates to TRUE, PHP will execute statement, and if it evaluates to FALSE - it'll ignore it. Also visit [PHP: elseif/else](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

```
if ($response['type'] === null) {
    echo "Response type is null";
    // Do something 
} else {
    echo "Response type is not null!";
    // Do something 
}
```